# Why is A union B also called "A or B"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In A union B, the element either belongs to A or B, or A and B right?
So shouldn't it be called A and/or B? Due to this I am unable to solve a problem in my textbook.

Comment: In math, "or" is inclusive.

Comment: Where is A union B also called "A or B"?

Comment: When we say "or" in mathematics we mean one thing, the other or both. That is why we can say the union of two sets $A \cup B$ is the set whose elements are in $A$ or in $B$ (it can be in both sets).

Comment: A correct answer is contained in the union of all answers given below.  Does that imply that only one answer below is correct?

Comment: @quasi I honestly think that's the best answer out of all of the ones below.

Comment: @user662650.You may accept one one the answers given below in case  you consider the question has effectively benn answered.

Comment: @user662650.- You may accept an answer for this question in case you consider one of the posts below have been really helpful :)

Answer (score 5):

Because the elements of $A \cup B$ are exactly those objects that [belong to $A$ **or** belong to $B$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Comment: I'd like to add [from my limited knowledge] an "or" mostly means an 'inclusive or' [x being in A or in B or even in both [A and B], like stated in the question "and/or"] as opposed to an 'exclusive or' (or XOR) where x shall be in A or B but not in both! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or

Answer (score 3):

The claim "$p$ or $q$" is true if either $p$ is true, or $q$ is true, or $p$ and $q$ are both true.

That is, the claim "I am human or I am over one meter tall" is true, because *at least one* of the subclaims is true (in this case, both are true)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we are in a university.

The President orders ( for some reason we do not care about)  the following thing: I want all math students and all students that play tennis to be present in the great hall tomorrow ( and no other person).

The next day, due to the strong authority of the President, all math students and all students playing tennis are present in the great  hall.

Certainly, ***the President has in front of him all the members of  the set : $M \cup T$ ( that is the union of set M and of set T)

with M = the set of all math students
and  T = the set of students playing tennis.

Now, ***what does the President know of any one of the students present there*** ( although he has possibly never met anyone of these students before)?

For example, what does the President know about David, one of the students that is there?

The ***only thing he knows for sure*** is that :

David is a math student ***OR*** David is a student that plays tennis.

Remark : of course, it could be the case David to be both a math student and a tennis player; but of this, the President has absolutely not idea.

In other words he only knows for sure that : ***one at least of these two propositions*** is true :

(1) David is a math student

(2) David is a student that plays tennis

and this " ***at least one***" is precisely ***what defines the inclusive OR*** operator in logic.

Since the same thing could be said about any student, one can say in general that :

The set : M U T is the set of all x such that (1) x is a math student **OR** (2) x is a student that plays tennis.

In symbols : $M \cup T$  = { $x$ | $x$ belongs to $M$ $\lor$ x belongs to $T$ }

You might say : but there are certainly students in the hall that both are maths students and play tennis.

You would be right, but notice  that if a student, say,  David is both a math student and a tennis player, this is precisely an excellent reason to say that he is at east one of these two things. So David belongs to the set  M **U** T  exactly in the same way as all students that are ***at least one*** of these two things : math student OR tennis player.

The OR that defines the union operation is ***inclusive***.

Comment: Well, at my university the president is a woman.

Answer (score 2):

The union of two sets $A,B$ is defined by the ''or'' operation in propositional logic:
$$A\cup B = \{x\mid x\in A\vee x\in B\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A `U` B are all the elements of set A and set B. Read as 'A or B' (A union B). 
Whereas,
A `Π` B are all the elements which set A and set B have in common. Read as 'A intersection B' (A and B).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Because the elements of $A\cup B$ are exactly those objects that either belong to $A$, or belong to $B$. The claim "$p$ or $q$" is true if either $p$ is true, or $q$ is true, or $p$ and $q$ are both true.

Answer (score 0):

In set theory, a union is a combination of all of the elements in sets *A* and *B*. Considering that it is a combination of both sets *A* and *B*, then we can place it with the word, 'or' which is equivalent to either set. For example, *A* = {2, 3, 4, 5} and *B* = {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, the union is the all the elements of *x* ∈ *A* or *x* ∈ *B*, hence it will be *A* ∪ *B* = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to say, "a union is a combination of all of the elements in sets $A$ or $B$"?